# filter on multiple columns with variables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parameters, multiple-columns, where-clause

I have an SQL table that looks like this:

[image]

```
DECLARE @BI_ResponsibleID INT , @CategoryID  INT , @ChangeRequestorID INT 

SET @BI_ResponsibleID = 5
SET @CategoryID = 3
SET @ChangeRequestorID = 4

SELECT TOP 4
      [BI_ResponsibleID],
      [CategoryID],
      [ChangeRequestorID]   
FROM [BI_Planning].[dbo].[tlbActivity]
```

I would like to be able to **filter** the columns depending on my variables value(s)

**E.G** *sometimes only @BI_ResponsibleID other times @CategoryID and @ChangeRequestorID and so on.....*

I this possible with my variables?

Comment: you want filter your result with one or more than variable?

Comment: Dynamic query is one option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use dynamic query something below. I'm assuming if the variable's values is zero you don't want to filter on that column.

```
// Not tested code
DECLARE @BI_ResponsibleID INT , @CategoryID  INT , @ChangeRequestorID INT 
DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(1000)


SET @BI_ResponsibleID = 5
SET @CategoryID = 3
SET @ChangeRequestorID = 4

SET @sqlCommand = 'TOP 4
      [BI_ResponsibleID],
      [CategoryID],
      [ChangeRequestorID]   
FROM [BI_Planning].[dbo].[tlbActivity] where 1 = 1 '

if(@BI_ResponsibleID != 0)
 set @sqlCommand +=  'AND BI_ResponsibleID = @BI_ResponsibleID '

 if(@CategoryID != 0)
 set @sqlCommand +=  'AND CategoryID = @CategoryID ' 

 if(@ChangeRequestorID != 0)
 set @sqlCommand +=  'AND ChangeRequestorID = @ChangeRequestorID '

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'@BI_ResponsibleID INT, @CategoryID INT, @ChangeRequestorID INT', @BI_ResponsibleID, @CategoryID, @ChangeRequestorID;
```

Comment: Great use of dynamic SQL here, and get's around the other answers which are using "catch-all queries" (which can massively suffer from performance issues). I'll admit, however, I'm not a fan of the use of the `1 = 1`; it can make the query analyser make odd decisions. If you can add logic to get around it's use, it would be even better. :)

Comment: I get an error: Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

Comment: @Nils - Updated the type of `@sqlCommand` in answer problem should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

DECLARE @BI_ResponsibleID INT , @CategoryID  INT , @ChangeRequestorID INT

```
SET @BI_ResponsibleID = 5
SET @CategoryID = 3
SET @ChangeRequestorID = 4

SELECT TOP 4
     [BI_ResponsibleID],
     [CategoryID],
     [ChangeRequestorID]   
FROM [BI_Planning].[dbo].[tlbActivity]
WHERE (ISNULL([BI_ResponsibleID],0) = @BI_ResponsibleID) 
    AND (ISNULL([CategoryID],0) = @CategoryID)
    AND (ISNULL([ChangeRequestorID],0) = @ChangeRequestorID)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution for you:

Using default value for null parameter like this

```
SET @BI_ResponsibleID = ISNULL(@BI_ResponsibleID, 0 );
SET @CategoryID = ISNULL(@CategoryID, 0 );
SET @ChangeRequestorID = ISNULL(@ChangeRequestorID, 0 );
```

And try this:

```
SELECT TOP 4
      [BI_ResponsibleID],
      [CategoryID],
      [ChangeRequestorID]   
FROM [BI_Planning].[dbo].[tlbActivity]
WHERE (@BI_ResponsibleID = 0 OR [BI_ResponsibleID] = @BI_ResponsibleID)
  AND (@CategoryID = 0 OR [CategoryID] = @CategoryID)
  AND (@ChangeRequestorID = 0 OR [ChangeRequestorID] = @ChangeRequestorID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I do not have tables and data, I cannot check this query. But this is how you can achieve it.

```
DECLARE @BI_ResponsibleID INT , @CategoryID  INT , @ChangeRequestorID INT 

SET @BI_ResponsibleID = 5
SET @CategoryID = 3
SET @ChangeRequestorID = 4

SELECT TOP 4
      [BI_ResponsibleID],
      [CategoryID],
      [ChangeRequestorID]   
FROM [BI_Planning].[dbo].[tlbActivity]
WHERE ( 1 = 1 OR ( @BI_ResponsibleID IS NOT NULL AND  Some Other condition using @BI_ResponsibleID))
    AND ( 1 = 1 OR ( @CategoryID IS NOT NULL AND  Some Other condition using @CategoryID))
    AND ( 1 = 1 OR ( @ChangeRequestorID IS NOT NULL AND  Some Other condition using @ChangeRequestorID))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @BI_ResponsibleID INT , @CategoryID  INT , @ChangeRequestorID INT 

SET @BI_ResponsibleID = 5
SET @CategoryID = 3
SET @ChangeRequestorID = 4

SELECT TOP 4
      [BI_ResponsibleID],
      [CategoryID],
      [ChangeRequestorID]   
FROM [BI_Planning].[dbo].[tlbActivity]
WHERE ( BI_ResponsibleID = @BI_ResponsibleID OR @BI_ResponsibleID IS NULL )
      AND ( CategoryID = @CategoryID OR @CategoryID IS NULL )
      AND ( ChangeRequestorID = @ChangeRequestorID OR @ChangeRequestorID IS NULL )
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is, include `OR` condition to check `NULL` parameters like this:

```
DECLARE @BI_ResponsibleID INT , @CategoryID  INT , @ChangeRequestorID INT 

SET @BI_ResponsibleID = 5
SET @CategoryID = 3
SET @ChangeRequestorID = 4

SELECT TOP 4
      [BI_ResponsibleID],
      [CategoryID],
      [ChangeRequestorID]   
FROM [BI_Planning].[dbo].[tlbActivity]
WHERE 
    (BI_ResponsibleID = @BI_ResponsibleID OR @BI_ResponsibleID IS NULL)
    AND (CategoryID = @CategoryID OR @CategoryID IS NULL)
    AND (ChangeRequestorID = @ChangeRequestorID OR @ChangeRequestorID IS NULL)
```

You may want to do this via stored proc like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcName
    @BI_ResponsibleID = NULL
    @CategoryID = NULL
    @ChangeRequestorID = NULL

AS

SELECT TOP 4
      [BI_ResponsibleID],
      [CategoryID],
      [ChangeRequestorID]   
FROM [BI_Planning].[dbo].[tlbActivity]
WHERE 
    (BI_ResponsibleID = @BI_ResponsibleID OR @BI_ResponsibleID IS NULL)
    AND (CategoryID = @CategoryID OR @CategoryID IS NULL)
    AND (ChangeRequestorID = @ChangeRequestorID OR @ChangeRequestorID IS NULL)

END
```

Comment: What happens if i only want to filter on @CategoryID = 3 and leave BI_ResponsibleID and ChangeRequestorID  blank?

Comment: @Nils in that case as well the query will work. it will take @CategoryID = 3 and other conditions as NULL. Only catch is, you need to give `set @ChangeRequestorID = NULL` , `set @BI_ResponsibleID = NULL`